# How to safely overwrite data in a full circular_buffer in C++

Tags: c++, circular-buffer

I currently try to wrap my head around how to safely handle the case that a circular buffer is full and the producer wants to insert data into it.
The reason is that I have a classic producer-consumer problem with a camera (producer) producing images and a viewer (consumer) showing them, both running in their own thread. Since I do not want to limit the cameras frame rate (maybe that is not the best idea, but let's assume it is), the producer might at some point overwrite images that the consumer has not yet processed.
As the images might be rather large, I would opt to not return them by value, but by reference or pointer. So once the buffer is full, it might occur that the producer would overwrite an image to which the consumer currently holds a pointer, probably even while the consumer reads its memory location. This, of course, is a behaviour that needs to be avoided, as the consumer does not expect to have the data changed under his fingers.

However, I wonder what would actually be the behaviour one would expect, and which would be the best, most encapsulated solution for this.

Since limiting the cameras frame rate is not desired, it would not be an option to simply pause the producer with a mutex or semaphore once it attempts to overwrite active images. So the only solution I can think of here is to skip the image currently handled by the consumer and overwrite the second oldest image instead. However, for this one would need a mechanism to indicate that the image is currently used. Maybe returning a `std::shared_ptr` when requesting an image and checking its `use_count` on overwriting images would be an option.

I tried to find similar questions, but couldn't. Any input how to solve this properly, or if this question is a non-issue since my basic idea is flawed, would help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: *Any input how to solve this properly* -- If you value your time, use [Boost circular buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html).  Then you can focus on the other aspects of your application, instead of trying to implement the circular buffer yourself.

Comment: Few strategies possible: inadequately large buffer has to grow, producers have to discard product, some product from buffer has to be discarded to make room, production rate has to be lowered, consumption rate has to be increased. Or some combination of those.

Comment: Use some form of triple buffering where a succesful read by the client will swap the read buffer to the last fully produced image. And then the read buffer will become the next write buffer. In the end a client cannot display faster then it can anyway. That is assuming data loss is acceptable. And no std::shared_ptr is not a good way to model this. Just return a non-owning pointer to the current (next) read buffer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, Boosts circular buffer definitely will be part of the solution, however, it does not provide thread safety and doesn't answer the question how to handle overwriting the correct image on its own. So it will need a wrapper taking care of this.

Comment: @ÖöTiib The goal is to discard the oldest image from the buffer that is not currently consumed, I guess. The question is how to do it properly. Or why to not do it like this

Comment: In what scenario do you want your producer to produce at a higher rate that the sum of your consumers (or just the one consumer) can consume it. This will necessarily overflow your memory at some point. Especially if you are streaming video frames, at some point the delay between production and consumption might not be intended. I think you first have to figure out the requirements: Is dropping frames okay to catch up to the producer or should the producer rate-limit itself?

Comment: I want to show a live view of a camera running. If the camera is slower than the viewer, all is good, the camera dictates the frame rate, nothing is ever overwritten or dropped. But if the viewer is slower than the camera, I don't want the camera to wait for the viewer, as it should always show live images. The fact that old images are dropped would be ok in that case.

Comment: If you have a circular buffer that is full, you have a few options: 1) Increase the size of the buffer and insert the new entry. 2) Overwrite the oldest entry in the buffer with the new entry. 3) Delay insertion a bit and hope the buffer has free space when you try again. 4) Drop the data you want to insert and hope the buffer has room next time you want to insert. 5) Clear the buffer and start inserting from scratch. 6) Something I have not thought of ;)

Comment: @RaimundSchlüßler boost::circular_buffer_space_optimized  already does it; you just push_back() and if there is no room then it overwrites whatever is front(). Assuming any consumer does same at start consumption moves front() away and pop_front(), that is exactly the oldest not consumed.

Comment: An easy way to prevent simultaneous access would be the use of an `std::atomic` containing a pointer: start of with every thread owning 1 element and each time a thread is done with the last element and needs a new one, call `exchange` on the atomic passing the element currently owned by the thread. Not sure how easy this would be to combine with your circular list; i guess that depends on the exact strategy you want to use when the producer or consumer exhausts the available elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easiest to abandon the idea of a true circular buffer. The main motivation for circular buffers is that they are the most efficient way to represent large queues of small records, since there is no per-record memory overhead (a typical example is an audio buffers with 16 or 32-bit samples), but this overhead becomes negligible once your records are sufficiently large, as in your use case: presumably, buffers containing video frames are quite large (kilobytes if not megabytes?), so there is little reason to keep them in contiguous memory. You might as well allocate the buffers on the heap and store pointers in a queue-like data structure.

For your problem it suffices to have:

1. A free list of pre-allocated buffers.
2. A list of filled buffers to be consumed.

Then the consumer does something like:

1. Grab a buffer from the front of list 2 (blocking if empty).
2. Process it.
3. Return the buffer to list 1 to be reused.

And the producer:

1. Grab a buffer from list 1, or if it is empty, grab it from the front of list 2 instead (this is how you end up overwriting the oldest filled buffer).
2. Fill the buffer.
3. Add the buffer to the back of list 2 to be processed.

The lists can be implemented simply with `std::deque<buffer*>`. Smart pointers are not necessary here because at no point is any buffer being shared: the buffer is either in the free list, in the queue, owned by the producer, or owned by the consumer, with nothing in between. Maybe std::unique_ptr<> is useful to guarantee that each buffer is freed exactly once.

What is important, however, is that access to the deques (or whatever data structure you decide to use) is synchronized. A simple mutex will probably suffice (combined with a semaphore to handle the cases where the consumer needs to block and wait in step 1). There are also lockless implementations of queues which you can use, but it's highly unlikely that the performance difference is big enough to matter for this use case.

Note that you can still allocate all the buffers in contiguous memory if you want. The important part is that you only store pointers in the queues so that synchronized access can be extremely fast.

Comment: That might actually be a good solution to the problem. It would ensure that images currently being consumed can never be overwritten, since they are not in the write list. The mutex would also only block for a short period of time, since I only deque/queue pointers.
Now I just wonder whether the pointer to the buffer currently being consumed could clean up behind himself when it goes out of scope and return the memory to the write list. So that one cannot forget to do step 3. of the consumer "Return the buffer to list 1 to be reused." by accident or due to an exception in the consumer code.

Comment: I ended up doing it as you proposed. With the small addition that I created a wrapper for the returned pointers, that returns the read/write pointer to the empty/full list automatically after it went out of scope.